# How to write functor instance in haskell with data constructors

Tags: haskell, functor

We are given

```
type ID = Int
data LST a
  = Leaf ID a
  | Node ID [LST a]
    deriving (Show, Eq)
```

How may I write a functor instance for LST, such that

```
instance Functor LST where
  fmap = something
```

Comment: If you’re being assigned this, you were probably taught something about it – did you try anything based on what you learned that didn’t work? It’s a good idea to include that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are, in general, two ways to construct an `Lst a` value, so start by enumerating them and noting the types of values bound to each name:

```
fmap f (Leaf i x) = ...  -- f :: a -> b, i :: Int, x :: a
fmap f (Node i xs) = ... --  f :: a -> b, i :: Int, xs :: [a]
```

Assuming that the results must depend on `f` somehow, there are only a couple of options for doing so:

1. Apply `f` to `x` to get a value of type `b`
2. Map `f` over `xs` to get a value of type `[b]`.

Using this, you can probably make a good guess at what the right-hand side of each definition should be. Once you've done that, you can check your definitions against the functor laws, specifically,

```
fmap id (Leaf i x) == id (Leaf i x)
fmap id (Node i xs) == id (Node i xs)

fmap (f.g) (Leaf i x) == fmap f (fmap g (Leaf i x))
fmap (f.g) (Node i xs) == fmap f (fmap g (Node i xs))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can let Haskell do the work with the [**`DeriveFunctor`** extension <sup>[ghc-doc]</sup>](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/deriving_extra.html#extension-DeriveFunctor):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

type ID = Int
data LST a
  = Leaf ID a
  | Node ID [LST a]
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor)
```

Comment: But i'm wondering what's behind this, could you please explain it to me? Thanks

Comment: You can enable `:set -ddump-deriv` to see the actual code GHC produces.